# Is there a way of operating on a generic type of Collection?

Tags: java, collections, set

I have a method that will do things to some form of collection. However is it possible to extend the number of types of collections to run the method on?
I don't mean a generic collections such as ArrayList but have the method work on ArrayLists, Arrays, Collections, Sets, Hashtables?

Comment: Arrays aren't Collections

Comment: Array and Hashtable are not Collections.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you share some code please?

Comment: On the other hand, a method that works on Collections ipso facto works on ArrayLists and Sets.

Comment: I know they are not collections, but I don't know how else to describe it. Some form of storage

Comment: Would you mind then re-formulate your question? So that we understand what your problem is?

Comment: I said "ArrayLists, Arrays, Collections, Sets, Hashtables?". Does that not show I know arrays and arraylists are not Collections? Don't know how I wasn't clear so sorry

Comment: As far as arrays and `Collection`s are concerned, take a look at the [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.sort%28java.util.List%29) of `Collections.sort` that reuses `Arrays.sort`. As far as `Map`s, there is a little mismatch in how a map _is-a_ collection: are we talking about the collection of keys, values or `Entry`s? In that case you can use the `keySet`, `values` and `entrySet` methods to reuse your method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't directly extend the method to support the other types you mentioned, you could accomplish this from an API standpoint by overloading methods. For example, if you implement a method to handle all collections:

```
public <T> void processData(Collection<T> data) { ... }
```

That will work for all types that implement `Collection`. You can overload this method for each type that isn't a `Collection`. For example:

```
public <T> void processData(T[] data) {
    processData(Arrays.asList(data));
}
```

In this example, you are re-using the same method that processes the `Collection` structure for arrays too. Each of the types that don't implement `Collection` or array will need another specialized overloaded method that either converts it to a `Collection`, or more likely, processes that data structure in a way that makes sense for it.

In the end, by overloading the methods, you can call the method by the same name and pass in a variety of types. So from an API standpoint, it always looks like you're calling the same method:

```
Collection<String> coll = new ArrayList<String>();
int[] arrayOfInts = new int[10];

// You can call processData on both of these types now
processData(coll);
processData(arrayOfInts);
```